# Should I programmatically validate entities in a container managed environment?

Tags: java, validation, jpa

I have annotated my JPA entities with some constraints (for example @NotNull, @Max, as well as some custom ones).

I know the container (Glassfish in this case) automatically validates the entities as soon as they're part of an SQL query (insert, update...). It works fine, of course, and the transaction is rolled back and an exception is thrown. Then only complaint I'd have is that the constraint's error message it's not printed in the log.

So I was wondering, should I just rely on the system that's already in place, or should I add some more validation logic in my EJB application?

For example:

```
public Long createJob(Job j) {
    em.persist(j);
    return j.getId();
}
```

This method creates a job in the database, the job entity is passed to the EJB from an application client that instantiates one as a simple object (no validation from the container in the client).
Should I use the Validation API in a method like this (nevermind its simplicity) or would it be redundant?

Comment: This is very broad. It depends on what type of validations you want to do in that method. If there are some complex rules that are not easy to validate in annotated example, or if you want to add validations but class definition is outside your control, then you should have a separate method for it. Or if you just want to call JPA bean-validation second time  (given entity manager already calls it, ofc), but substitute error messages to something different maybe. If you intend neither, then probably not.